# How to memset a 2D arrray?

Tags: c++

I want to memset a 2D array to 0. Here's my code.. But it always giving me seg fault;

```
      bool **visited=new bool*[m];
         for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
           visited[i] = new bool[m];
```

I have tried `memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited[0][0]) * m * m);` and `memset(visited, 0, sizeof visited);` , But nonw of this works and gives me segfault. how do I do that?

Comment: If you are using STL you should try using vector<bool> instead of array of booleans.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: If `m` is known, then use `bitset` instead.

Comment: You don't have a 2D array. You have a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is not contiguous since it is not actually a multi-dimensional array. It's an array of arrays, sometimes known as a jagged array.

So, your rows can, and will, be disjoint. Hence you'll need to call memset on each row.

```
bool **visited=new bool*[m];
for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
{
    visited[i] = new bool[m];
    memset(visited[i], 0, sizeof(visited[i][0]) * m);
}
```

Although, I can't refrain from pointing out that you should probably be using C++ features rather than writing what appears to be C with the use of the new operator.

Comment: Indeed, C++ should be utilized more. ;-)

Comment: What C++ feature should I use? vector<vector<int> > ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841170/how-to-define-a-2d-array-in-c-and-stl-without-memory-manipulation  but even if you used pointers there are smart pointers, and std::fill